# How do you adjust the arrows in a ggplot of a ggdag?

Tags: r, ggplot2, directed-acyclic-graphs

Consider the problem of creating plots of Directed Acyclic Graphs (DAGs) using `ggdag` and `ggplot2` in `R`.  (Introductory documentation for `ggdag` can be found [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggdag/vignettes/intro-to-ggdag.html).)  The default plot settings give a particular node size, which can be altered in the options.  However, the lengths of the arrows appears to be constructed to match the default node sizes and I am unsure how to change them to match an alternative node size.

As an illustration of this problem, I have generated two DAG plots below.  The first plot uses the default node size (so far as I can tell, the standard size is approx `size = 20`) and the second plot changes the node size to `size = 40`.  As you can see, in the first plot the arrows go near to the nodes and this looks nice.  However, in the second plot the arrows are unchanged, so now they go inside the nodes, which is not what I want.  How do I make the second set of arrows shorter, so that they go near to the nodes without going into them?

```
#Load required libraries
library(ggdag)
library(ggplot2)

#Create a tidy DAG
DAG <- dagify(y ~ x)
DAG <- tidy_dagitty(DAG)

#Plot the DAG with default nodes
PLOT1 <- ggplot(ggplot2::aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend), data = DAG) +
         geom_dag_point(colour = 'LightBlue') +
         geom_dag_edges() +
         geom_dag_text(colour = 'white') +
         theme_dag()
PLOT1

#Plot the DAG with bigger nodes
PLOT2 <- ggplot(ggplot2::aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend), data = DAG) +
         geom_dag_point(colour = 'LightBlue', size = 40) +
         geom_dag_edges() +
         geom_dag_text(colour = 'white') +
         theme_dag()
PLOT2
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I created a function which shortens the xend and yend values output by `tidy_dagitty()`. This at least fixes the head of the arrow. I have primarily used the `ggdag` functions such as `ggdag` or `ggdag_status()` to create the plot which places arrows behind the nodes - this makes the x node look reasonable so this fix is enough for me. May require some experimentation with the `shorten_distance`.

```
shorten_dag_arrows <- function(tidy_dag, shorten_distance){
  
  # Update underlying ggdag object
  tidy_dag$data <- dplyr::mutate(tidy_dag$data, slope = (yend - y) / (xend - x), # Calculate slope of line
                  distance = sqrt((xend-x)^2 + (yend - y)^2), # Calculate total distance of line
                  proportion = shorten_distance/distance, # Calculate proportion by which to be shortened
                  xend = (1-proportion)*xend + (proportion*x), # Shorten xend
                  yend = (1-proportion)*yend + (proportion*y)) %>% # Shorten yend
    dplyr::select(-slope, -distance, -proportion) # Drop intermediate values
  
  return(tidy_dag)
}

DAG <- shorten_dag_arrows(DAG, shorten_distance = 0.06)

PLOT3 <- ggplot(ggplot2::aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend), data = DAG) +
  geom_dag_point(colour = 'LightBlue', size = 40) +
  geom_dag_edges() +
  geom_dag_text(colour = 'white') +
  theme_dag()
PLOT3
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on c_j_fairfield's function above, I made one that also adjusts the tail of the arrow. When plotting, just include `aes(x = xstart, y = ystart)` in your `geom_dag_edges()`.

Here, you input the proportion by which to shorten directly, but you could easily reinstate `shorten_distance` if needed.

```
shorten_dag_arrows <- function(tidy_dag, proportion){
# Update underlying ggdag object
tidy_dag$data <- dplyr::mutate(tidy_dag$data, 
                             xend = (1-proportion/2)*(xend - x) + x, 
                             yend = (1-proportion/2)*(yend - y) + y,
                             xstart = (1-proportion/2)*(x - xend) + xend,
                             ystart = (1-proportion/2)*(y-yend) + yend)
return(tidy_dag)
}
```